# Netbeans syntax coloring

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

L.S.,

I am new to Netbeans. I'm using IDE 6.9.1 for work with PHP. Is it possible to define your own syntax coloring rules? I would like the coloring to distinguish between class attributes and class methods.

Much obliged.

Comment: You found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Netbeans preferences there is a Fonts and Colors tab where you can modify all the syntax coloring that is used, if you want you can create a profile to save these settings which will allow you to revert to default if you choose to at a later date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the F&C tab, but I was hoping that I could also define extra rules that you can't find in the default setup. I would like to distinguish between different types of identifiers for example (defines, class attributes, etc.) so that they don't all have the same color. Maybe through some configuration files? M.O.